# Creating liferay plugin and getting error

Tags: eclipse, plugins, liferay, liferay-ide

Please help me to resolve this error. Whenever I try to create `liferay` plugin project I am getting an error stating:

```
"Error creating liferay plugin project. please see the log for more detail"
```

In the log it is showing:

> caused by
>   :java.ioFileNotFoundException:source'home/raman......(path)'does not
>   exist...

Screenshot of the error (log file):

[image]

Comment: I believe this type of question would best be asked over on the Liferay IDE forums here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/category/4627757

Comment: okk thanks for link @gamerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I resolve my problem when we create liferay plugin first-time it need internet connection to download require dependency and in my office there is restriction in ip address so basically it block the url address from where dependency are downloading and result is I am not able to create liferay plugin so

1) first solution is that you need to remove the restriction of that url (dependency) from your work area if it set.

2) second solution is that you can download require dependencies on your own home area where there is no restriction over ip address and copy that eclipse and plugin folder into your office desktop or you can say replace it with older one.

**i chose the second option**